# Custom events in Firebase analytics console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have followed the Firebase Analytics start guide to import my google-analytics project into Firebase. Everything went fine except that I cannot see any new data (custom events and new users) while I'm doing my tests.

There is no real-time functionality so at least I'm expected to see my custom events published in the dashboard as soon as they are emitted by the app.

Here an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

`mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("test_event", null);`

From the logcat I can see:

`Logging event (FE): test_event`

but the analytics dashboard remains empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The events don't turn up right away - it requires the same processing as for any data to appear in the dashboard. This should be within 24 hours, and may be as fast as a few hours, depending on when the processing jobs run.

Its also worth noting the default view in the console does is the 30 days to yesterday. Select the drop down on the top right and select *Today* to see the most recent events

Answer (score 2):

As Ian Barber mentioned the default view excludes today but you can change the date picker to today. It usually takes few hours for the events to appear in the Firebase Analytics reports (like 3-4 hours). BigQuery export happens once a day.

Comment: yeah, I think they need to change that otherwise it will be a step backward comparing to google analytics. I'm thinking also to the real-time feature.

Comment: Daniele, Google Analytics for Android works exactly the same way, except the delay is 30 minutes instead of 60. App developer can not control the dispatching interval on Google Play Devices (most phones). On non play devices developer can control the dispatching interval