# Google Firebase integration in android application

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrated Firebase in android app, followed all the steps as mentioned in docs.
Integrated google-services.json file and added required lines in project  and app level gradle.

Added analytics library : com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1

Android studio version :2.1.2

Compiled using 24 sdk.

The app is build without errors and its running in device,but the Firebase Analytics dashboard is empty.

I am getting crash reports but analytics are not displayed

Also added firebase instance in mainactivity.

Please help..thanks

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1068
        versionName "1.0.6.8"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.0.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: firebase analytic require about 24 hours before you could see results

Comment: I have integrated 4 days ago... Crash reports are displayed but Analytics are empty.

Comment: but it should work without adding any line of code , are you sure you added the firebase analytic library to the gradle folder?

Comment: Yes, i have added the analytics library.                                                                                              com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1

Comment: post the build.gradle file plz

Comment: did you add this apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to the gradle?

Comment: try making an instance of class FirebaseAnalytics ,if compiler doesn't recognize the class ,means something is wrong

Comment: Edited the Question posted the build.gradle file code...

Comment: I have created the instance also...

Comment: i have no idea :) ,i did it exactly like you and works good

Comment: @Navya : May be related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378634/custom-events-in-firebase-analytics-console

Answer (score 0):

Instant Run in Android Studio prior to version 2.2 is incompatible with Firebase Analytics

[image]

Refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)